# How to load multiple list in android listfragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have multiple listfragments in my android app.I want to load second list fragment by taking the inputs from first listfragment.
How to load the second listfragment by taking the position of click from first fragment.
Currently second listfragment shows only loading.

Answer (score 0):

The question implies that you know how to display new fragments and you know how to set click events for your list items. So you should define the following code in your second list fragment:

```
public class SecondListFragment extends ListFragment {

public static SecondListFragment newInstance(int positionFromPreviousList){
            SecondListFragment f = new SecondListFragment();

            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("position", positionFromPreviousList);
            f.setArguments(args);

            return f;
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

            ...

            int position = getArguments().getInt("position");
            //Show what you want with this position
            ...
        }
}
```

In your list item click listener initialize new fragment as

```
Fragment fr = SecondListFagment(position);
```